# NATS WEBSOCKET Python WebSocket Connection

Tags: python, websocket, nats.io

I want to do the following thing:
I want to make a websocket, which prints me all events about esports and I want to use https://sofascore.com
I've inspected the network requests as usual and it seems that I need to send a Auth WebSocket Content first, then one for subscribing the right sport and then I will receive my events I need.

I've wrote the following code:

```py
import websockets
import asyncio
from websockets.extensions import permessage_deflate


async def esports():
    async with websockets.connect('wss://ws.sofascore.com:9222/', compression='deflate') as websocket:
        msg = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"From Server: {msg}")
        t = await websocket.send(
            'CONNECT {"no_responders":true,"protocol":1,"verbose":false,"pedantic":false,"user":"none","pass":"none","lang":"nats.ws","version":"1.8.1","headers":true}')
        await websocket.send("PING")
        pong = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"From Server: {pong}")
        await websocket.send(
            'SUB sport.esports 6')
        while (True):
            msg = await websocket.recv()
            print(f"From Server: {msg}")



asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(esports())
```

I know that the websocket is compressed as permessage_deflate, when I saw into the request headers of the websocket.

But I still get an error:

```yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Coding\Desktop\websockett.py", line 23, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(esports())
  File "C:\Users\Coding\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Coding\Desktop\websockett.py", line 15, in esports
    await websocket.send(
  File "C:\Users\Coding\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 620, in send
    await self.ensure_open()
  File "C:\Users\Coding\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 921, in ensure_open
    raise self.connection_closed_exc()
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: received 1008 (policy violation) Authentication Timeout; then sent 1008 (policy violation) Authentication Timeout

Process finished with exit code 1
```

EDIT:

I have now found out that the whole thing works with the Nats network. Is there any way to use Nats with a Libary that also supports the websockets?

Haven't found one on github or pypi unfortunately....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you would be able to use the [nats-py library](https://pypi.org/project/nats-py/):

```python
import asyncio
import nats


async def handler(msg):
    print(f"From server: {msg}")


async def main():
    nc = await nats.connect("wss://ws.sofascore.com:9222")
    await nc.subscribe("sport.esports", cb=handler)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

However, this library does not currently support connecting with WebSockets, so
the above doesn't work (yet - it looks like it's [being worked on](https://github.com/nats-io/nats.py/pull/356) right
now).

For your code, the only reason it fails is that the messages you're sending
don't end with `\r\n`, which the [NATS protocol](https://docs.nats.io/reference/reference-protocols/nats-protocol) requires. The code works as
expected with this change:

```python
import asyncio
import websockets


async def esports():
    async with websockets.connect('wss://ws.sofascore.com:9222') as websocket:
        msg = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"From Server: {msg}")

        await websocket.send(
            'CONNECT {"no_responders":true,"protocol":1,"verbose":false,"pedantic":false,"user":"none","pass":"none","lang":"nats.ws","version":"1.8.1","headers":true}\r\n'
        )

        await websocket.send("SUB sport.esports 1\r\n")

        async for msg in websocket:
            print(f"From Server: {msg}")


asyncio.run(esports())
```

Of course this will eventually get disconnected because it doesn't respond to
`PING` messages. Here's a little more fleshed out script which implements enough
of the NATS protocol to log the `sport.esports` messages:

```python
import asyncio
import json
import textwrap

from dataclasses import dataclass

import websockets


class SofaError(Exception):
    pass


def message_string(message, data=None, pretty=False):
    s = message
    if data is not None:
        if pretty:
            s += json.dumps(data, indent=2)
        else:
            s += json.dumps(data, separators=(",", ":"))
    return s


def log(pre, message, data=None):
    print(textwrap.indent(message_string(message, data, True), pre))


def recv_log(message, data=None):
    log("< ", message, data)


async def send(websocket, message, data=None):
    log("> ", message, data)
    data = (message_string(message, data, False) + "\r\n").encode()
    await websocket.send(data)


async def connect_and_subscribe(websocket):
    connect_options = {
        "no_responders": True,
        "protocol": 1,
        "verbose": False,
        "pedantic": False,
        "user": "none",
        "pass": "none",
        "lang": "nats.ws",
        "version": "1.8.1",
        "headers": True,
    }
    await send(websocket, "CONNECT ", connect_options)
    await send(websocket, "SUB sport.esports 1")


@dataclass
class NatsMsg:
    subject: str
    sid: str
    reply_to: str
    size: int
    payload: bytes


def parse_msg(info_line, pending_data):
    if not info_line:
        raise SofaError("No payload information received")

    info = [b.decode(errors="replace") for b in info_line.split(b" ")]

    if len(info) == 3:
        subject, sid, size = info
        reply_to = None
    elif len(info) == 4:
        subject, sid, reply_to, size = info
    else:
        raise SofaError("Unrecognized info format")

    try:
        size = int(size)
    except ValueError:
        raise SofaError("Bad payload size")

    if len(pending_data) < size:
        raise SofaError("Incomplete payload")

    payload = pending_data[:size]
    pending_data = pending_data[size:]

    return NatsMsg(subject, sid, reply_to, size, payload), pending_data


async def handler(websocket, ws_message, connected):
    while len(ws_message):
        nats_message, _, ws_message = ws_message.partition(b"\r\n")
        if not nats_message:
            continue

        op, _, rest = nats_message.partition(b" ")

        if op == b"-ERR":
            recv_log(nats_message.decode(errors="replace"))
            err = rest.strip(b"'").decode(errors="replace") if rest else "(No message received)"
            raise SofaError(f"Server error: {err}")

        elif op == b"INFO":
            info_options = json.loads(rest) if rest else None
            recv_log("INFO ", info_options)

            if not connected:
                await connect_and_subscribe(websocket)
                connected = True

        elif op == b"PING":
            recv_log("PING")
            await send(websocket, "PONG")

        elif op == b"MSG":
            try:
                msg, ws_message = parse_msg(rest, ws_message)
            except SofaError as e:
                recv_log(f"MSG (Error: {e}) {rest}")
                continue

            msg_info = (
                f"MSG subject={msg.subject} sid={msg.sid} "
                f"reply-to={msg.reply_to} nbytes={msg.size}:\n"
            )

            try:
                decoded = msg.payload.decode()
                data = json.loads(decoded)
            except UnicodeError:
                recv_log(f"{msg_info}{msg.payload}")
            except json.JSONDecodeError:
                recv_log(f"{msg_info}{decoded}")
            else:
                recv_log(msg_info, data)

        else:
            recv_log(f"(Unhandled op) {nats_message.decode(errors='replace')}")

    return connected


async def main():
    async with websockets.connect("wss://ws.sofascore.com:9222") as websocket:
        connected = False
        async for message in websocket:
            connected = await handler(websocket, message, connected)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much for the help! 

It's working as I wanted to.